Application of Bertrand's postulate
We can use Bertrand's Conjecture ( that for any integer $n \not= 0$, there exists at least one prime number $$ with $n < p \leq 2n$ ) to demonstrate the following proposition:

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus\left\{0\right\}$ , the rational number such that:
$$
H_{2n} = \sum_{k = 1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}\quad
\mbox{is}\ \underline{never}\ \mbox{an integer}
$$
What is the demonstration ?.


Note that, in that duplicate, the Bertrand based proof is described in the question itself.  The posted solutions describe some non-Bertrand methods.

Key idea: Write all the fractions in the sum with the common denominator $2n!$
Let $M_i$ denote the product $$1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot\ldots\cdot(i-2)\cdot(i-1)\cdot(i+1)\cdot(i+2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-1)\cdot2n$$ i.e., $M_i = \dfrac{2n!}{i}$ for $1 \le i \le 2n$. Each $M_i$ is clearly an integer.
We can write $H_{2n}$ by the common denominator $2n!$ as $$H_{2n} = \dfrac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n} M_i}{2n!}.$$
Using Bertrand's Postulate, Let $p$ be a prime such that $n < p \le 2n$. Notice that this implies $2p>2n$, so no other multiple of $p$ is among $\{ 1,2,\ldots,2n \}$.
Now, in the fraction $\dfrac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n} M_i}{2n!}$, notice that:

The denominator $2n!$ is divisible by $p$.
For $i \neq p$, the term $M_i$ is divisible by $p$.
$M_p$ is not divisible by $p$.

Overall, in the fraction $\dfrac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n} M_i}{2n!}$, the numerator is not divisible by $p$ but the denominator is divisible by $p$. Therefore, the fraction itself in not an integer. $\blacksquare$
